# Best way to test a linux distro?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-distributions

I'm not sure if it the good place to ask this.
I'm a little lost with all the StackExchange places.

I wish to test a few linux distro (4-5 distros) for a late 2019 laptop (asus zenbook pro).

I've try 2 distro with VirtualBox. I work well. Maybe too well:

1/ Does linux use the VirtualBox drivers, and not the laptop drivers?
That's mean I didn't test the distro compatibility.

I was thinking of partitioning the disk (maybe 50Go), then try all the distro on it.

Maybe It's more safe to install linux on a USB drive (to avoid a bad command like "use the whole disk" missclick).

2 / Could you give me some advices about the best practive to test a distro?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: First thing to do is narrow down your search. What do you want from the install? Also, what flavour? KDE? Gnome? XFCE? Once you have a shortlist of candidate distros, you can work out what you'll need to run them.

Comment: Your question is really vague. What do you mean by "testing a distro"? Distros contain thousands of different software packages, do you care about how they work, if they work, if it fits in someone's workflow, if it's easy to administer by a user, or maybe if it's easy to administer by a centralized IT department, if there is compatibility with non-Linux ecosystems, etc. etc. etc. That's not even considering hardware compatibility questions, like does everything work on this particular laptop, how efficient is power management, etc. Your question needs to be much, much more focused.

Comment: I first select the distro that work with my laptop hardware, then I'll choose the more confortable to me. I though that the "flavor" wasn't a key point because it's maybe possible to change the  desktop environnement (or to learn how to use it). I'll try those distro first: Manjaro, Linux Mint, Pop, MX Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to test Linux distros:

- You can try them as virtual machines (with VMware or Virtual Box), but this method is sometimes limited when you want to try some features (like WiFi support, ...)
- Another way, as you mentioned, is the dual boot, when you partition your HDD in order to install the distro on this specific partition. You can use "GParted live" for example to partition the disk, or built-in tools that comes with Linux distros installer most of the times.
- But the best way (for me) is the "[live](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/live-booting-linux/)" method. When you'll boot on your device to install Linux, most of the time you'll have the possibility to choose whether you want to install the distro or run it in "live" mode. This will allow you to run Linux with all hardware compatibility of your laptop without installing it on your HDD.

Comment: Thanks, does the live linux server can found all the drivers like a install linux? For exemple, Ubuntu live doesn't found the trackpad.

Comment: The live linux will use default drivers for your hardware. If you want specific drivers, maybe the best way is to use the "live persistent" mode and install drivers manually.

Comment: I though that a live persistant was about the data will persist after shutting down the live session. What's the link with the drivers?